# filter using value in lookup in CSOM

Tags: office-365, csom, 2016

I am using the below query to filter using lookup value

```
List list = parentCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'ProjectFolder'/><Value Type = 'Lookup'>" + filtervalue +"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
parentCtx.Load(collListItem);
parentCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

After this when I debug, the count of  `collListItem`  is 0.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing one important line of code here.

```
ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
```

Just place this line of code before

```
parentCtx.Load(collListItem);
```

And you will get your desired result.

Your final code should look like this:

```
List list = parentCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'ProjectFolder'/><Value Type = 'Lookup'>" + filtervalue +"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
parentCtx.Load(collListItem);
parentCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```